# App Engine's URLFetch: http GET works locally but not when deployed to GAE on a specific URL

Tags: java, http, google-app-engine, get

**The Problem:**

Locally my application works fine. My HTTP GET returns code 200 and a final URL of: http://vow.mlspin.com/clients/index.aspx?

The rest of my application works great too.

When I deploy my code to GAE servers (I use the Eclipse plugin to do my deployment) my application ceases to work because the wrong html page is returned!
the return code is still 200, but the URL is now (final URL): http://vow.mlspin.com/clients/signin.aspx?id=

**My Question is:** Is there a problem with redirects? Are the google app engine servers somehow blacklisted? What am I doing wrong here? Has anyone encountered this before?

The closest question I've found was this one: [Http GET from GAE Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412685/http-get-from-gae-java) I've implemented this suggestion but it hasn't worked for me so far.

Thank you all in advance!

Additional Info -> below are HTTPResponse headers from the same exact GET request, one from the local deployment and the other from the GAE deployment.

**Local HTTP Response Headers**

```
Date :: Tue, 24 Apr 2012 04:12:32 GMT
Server :: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By :: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version :: 2.0.50727
P3P :: CP="NOI DSP COR NID ADMa OPTa OUR NOR"
Cache-Control :: no-cache
Pragma :: no-cache
Expires :: -1
Content-Type :: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length :: 133704
```

**Deployed HTTP Response Headers**

```
date :: Tue, 24 Apr 2012 04:11:19 GMT
server :: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
x-powered-by :: ASP.NET
x-aspnet-version :: 2.0.50727
p3p :: CP="NOI DSP COR NID ADMa OPTa OUR NOR"
cache-control :: private
content-type :: text/html; charset=utf-8
content-length :: 4991
x-google-cache-control :: remote-fetch
via :: HTTP/1.1 GWA
```

**How I'm crafting my requests:**

First I tried the easy way

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(baseMLSURL).get();
```

then I tried to go low level and just use java.net

```
private String getHttpFromServer(String url) throws IOException
    log.severe("getting http from: "+ url);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    URL yahoo = new URL(url);
    URLConnection yc = yahoo.openConnection();
    yc.setRequestProperty("Host", "vow.mlspin.com");
    yc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(
                            yc.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(inputLine.replaceAll("&nbsp", " ")+"\r\n");
    }
    in.close();

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Finally I've also tried to use Google's URLFetcher

```
private String getHttpUsingFetchService(String url) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    URLFetchService fetchService = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService();
    HTTPResponse targetResponse = fetchService.fetch(new URL(url)); // Error
    log.severe("Code returned from request: "+targetResponse.getResponseCode());
    log.severe("final URL: "+targetResponse.getFinalUrl());
    String result = new String(targetResponse.getContent());
    return result.replaceAll("&nbsp;", " ");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We had something similar here a few months ago. In the end the mystery was that the site redirected to itself and expected to see some cookie it set back. But the urlfetch redirect handling doesn't send any cookies it receives. It's possible that the urlfetch emulation when running locally does something different with cookies.

If you can't get this to work, you may want to turn off redirect following in urlfetch and manage redirects and cookies yourself.

Comment: That's great advice, I'm going to try it tonight. See what I can come up with.

Comment: **update** @guido-van-rossum I've tried turning off redirects and managing cookies myself, but after 4 redirects and setting of two cookies the server still finally redirects me to the login page! I'm at a bit of a loss here. I've tried all sorts of combinations of setting the two cookies i was getting from the server, but each time - no joy. Is there any other way around this?

Comment: Thanks for this information. That's absolutely terrible design. I've spent ages trying to work out why my code works locally but fails miserably on AppEngine.

Answer (score 0):

The service you're trying to access requires authentication. Try visiting the first URL you posted in a new browser or an incognito window - you'll be redirected to the second URL. You need to perform the signin steps using your app, then take the cookies you're issued and send them on all subsequent requests.

Comment: You're correct authentication is required, but this mls website just allows you to put the user id and password right into the GET request. When I craft my initial GET request I do append my mls user id and password. Here's what the url string looks like: final String baseMLSURL = "http://vow.mlspin.com/?cid="+mlsUID+"&pass="+mlsPass+"";

Comment: @eak0703 Well, clearly it doesn't like your authentication credentials - it's sending you a redirect to the login page. Why it does that depends entirely on what its logic is for doing so.

Comment: The strange thing is that I've hardcoded the user id and password and when I deploy to a locally running Jetty (or whatever server google's eclipse plugin is using) I have no problems. I issue my GET and am returned the "logged in" portal page.  As soon as I deploy to the GAE servers I issue the same exact GET request but get back a different page.

Comment: I think the problem is with the proxy server that sits between whatever server my app is ending up on and "the internet".  For some reason this proxy is not keeping or purposely truncating cookies that are supposed to be set.  I've tried manually not following redirects and can see cookies coming back but can't seem to figure out the order for submitting a request with all of the proper cookies. Would you know any reason why the normal followRedirects behavior would cease working after deploying to google servers?

Comment: Yes, the code that implements followRedirects is completely different in the dev server than it is on the production servers. This is because the way urlfetch is implemented is completely different in the two cases. You're pretty much on your own reverse-engineering what the service you're trying to access wants.